# Ошибка в pygame TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not pygame.Rect

Tags: python, pygame

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
D:\Рабочий стол\Flappy Floppa>python bird.py
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Рабочий стол\Flappy Floppa\bird.py", line 92, in <module>
    window.blit(imgFON, fon)
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not pygame.Rect
```

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
FPS = 60

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

imgFON = pygame.image.load('images/fon.png')
imgBIRD = pygame.image.load('images/bird.png')
imgPB = pygame.image.load('images/PB.png')
imgPT = pygame.image.load('images/PT.png')
py, sy, ay = HEIGHT // 2, 0, 0
player = pygame.Rect(HEIGHT // 3, py, 50, 50)

state = 'start'
timer = 10

pipes = []
bges = []

bges.append(pygame.Rect(0, 0, 288, 512))

play = True
while play:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            play = False

    press = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    click = press[0] or keys[pygame.K_SPACE]

    if timer > 0:
        timer -= 1

    for i in range(len(bges)-1, -1, -1):
        imgFON = bges[i]
        imgFON.x -= 1

    if imgFON.right < 0:
        bges.remove(imgFON)

    for i in range(len(pipes)-1, -1, -1):
        pipe = pipes[i]
        pipe.x -= 3

        if pipe.right < 0:
            pipes.remove(pipe)


    if state == 'start':
        if click and timer == 0 and len(pipes) == 0:
            state = 'play'

        py += (HEIGHT // 2 - py) * 0.1
        player.y = py

    elif state == 'play':
        if click:
            ay = -2
        else:
            ay = 0

        py += sy
        sy = (sy + ay + 1) * 0.98
        player.y = py 

        if len(pipes) == 0 or pipes[len(pipes)-1].x < WIDTH - 200:
            pipes.append(pygame.Rect(WIDTH, 0, 52, 200))
            pipes.append(pygame.Rect(WIDTH, 400, 52, 200))

        if player.top < 0 or player.bottom > HEIGHT:
            state = 'fall'

        for pipe in pipes:
            if player.colliderect(pipe):
                state = 'fall'

    elif state == 'fall':
        sy, ay = 0, 0
        state = 'start'
        timer = 60
    else:
        pass



    window.fill(pygame.Color('black'))
    for fon in bges:
        window.blit(imgFON, fon)
    for pipe in pipes:
        if pipe.y == 0:
            rect = imgPB.get_rect(bottomleft = pipe.bottomleft)
            window.blit(imgPB, rect)
        else:
            rect = imgPT.get_rect(topleft = pipe.topleft)
            window.blit(imgPT, rect)

    window.blit(imgBIRD, player)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

**UPD.**

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
FPS = 60

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

imgFON = pygame.image.load('images/fon.png')
imgBIRD = pygame.image.load('images/bird.png')
imgPB = pygame.image.load('images/PB.png')
imgPT = pygame.image.load('images/PT.png')
py, sy, ay = HEIGHT // 2, 0, 0
player = pygame.Rect(HEIGHT // 3, py, 50, 50)

state = 'start'
timer = 10

pipes = []
bges = []

bges.append(pygame.Surface(0, 0, 288, 512))

play = True
while play:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            play = False

    press = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    click = press[0] or keys[pygame.K_SPACE]

    if timer > 0:
        timer -= 1

    for fon in reversed(bges):
        imgFON.x -= 1

    if imgFON.right < 0:
        bges.remove(imgFON)

    for i in range(len(pipes)-1, -1, -1):
        pipe = pipes[i]
        pipe.x -= 3

        if pipe.right < 0:
            pipes.remove(pipe)


    if state == 'start':
        if click and timer == 0 and len(pipes) == 0:
            state = 'play'

        py += (HEIGHT // 2 - py) * 0.1
        player.y = py

    elif state == 'play':
        if click:
            ay = -2
        else:
            ay = 0

        py += sy
        sy = (sy + ay + 1) * 0.98
        player.y = py 

        if len(pipes) == 0 or pipes[len(pipes)-1].x < WIDTH - 200:
            pipes.append(pygame.Rect(WIDTH, 0, 52, 200))
            pipes.append(pygame.Rect(WIDTH, 400, 52, 200))

        if player.top < 0 or player.bottom > HEIGHT:
            state = 'fall'

        for pipe in pipes:
            if player.colliderect(pipe):
                state = 'fall'

    elif state == 'fall':
        sy, ay = 0, 0
        state = 'start'
        timer = 60
    else:
        pass



    window.fill(pygame.Color('black'))
    for fon in bges:
        window.blit(imgFON, fon)
    for pipe in pipes:
        if pipe.y == 0:
            rect = imgPB.get_rect(bottomleft = pipe.bottomleft)
            window.blit(imgPB, rect)
        else:
            rect = imgPT.get_rect(topleft = pipe.topleft)
            window.blit(imgPT, rect)

    window.blit(imgBIRD, player)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

**UPD. Еще один вариант исправления** Дело было все в том что imgFON хранил в себе картинку, а после я пытался туда же сохранить bges[i], то есть в этой переменной уже хранилась картинка, а я пытался туда добавить еще список bges[], решение было лишь создать новую переменную, например fon. **Если что то неправильно объяснил или не так назвал, извините, только учусь**

```
for i in range(len(bges)-1, -1, -1):
        imgFON = bges[i]
        imgFON.x -= 1
```

**UPD. Ниже прикрепляю рабочий код**

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
FPS = 60

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

imgBG = pygame.image.load('images/fon.png')
imgBIRD = pygame.image.load('images/bird.png')
imgPB = pygame.image.load('images/PB.png')
imgPT = pygame.image.load('images/PT.png')
py, sy, ay = HEIGHT // 2, 0, 0
player = pygame.Rect(HEIGHT // 3, py, 50, 50)

state = 'start'
timer = 10

pipes = []
bges = []

bges.append(pygame.Rect(0, 0, 288, 512))

play = True
while play:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            play = False

    press = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    click = press[0] or keys[pygame.K_SPACE]

    if timer > 0:
        timer -= 1


    
    for i in range(len(bges)-1, -1, -1):
        fon = bges[i]
        fon.x -= 1

        if fon.right < 0:
            bges.remove(fon)


    for i in range(len(pipes)-1, -1, -1):
        pipe = pipes[i]
        pipe.x -= 3

        if pipe.right < 0:
            pipes.remove(pipe)

    if state == 'start':
        if click and timer == 0 and len(pipes) == 0:
            state = 'play'

        py += (HEIGHT // 2 - py) * 0.1
        player.y = py

    elif state == 'play':
        if click:
            ay = -2
        else:
            ay = 0

        py += sy
        sy = (sy + ay + 1) * 0.98
        player.y = py 

        if len(pipes) == 0 or pipes[len(pipes)-1].x < WIDTH - 200:
            pipes.append(pygame.Rect(WIDTH, 0, 52, 200))
            pipes.append(pygame.Rect(WIDTH, 400, 52, 200))

        if player.top < 0 or player.bottom > HEIGHT:
            state = 'fall'

        for pipe in pipes:
            if player.colliderect(pipe):
                state = 'fall'

    elif state == 'fall':
        sy, ay = 0, 0
        state = 'start'
        timer = 60
    else:
        pass



    window.fill(pygame.Color('black'))
    for fon in bges:
        window.blit(imgBG, fon)
    for pipe in pipes:
        if pipe.y == 0:
            rect = imgPB.get_rect(bottomleft = pipe.bottomleft)
            window.blit(imgPB, rect)
        else:
            rect = imgPT.get_rect(topleft = pipe.topleft)
            window.blit(imgPT, rect)

    window.blit(imgBIRD, player)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `window.blit(imgFON, fon)` у вас `imgFON` является `Rect`, а не `Surface`

В одном из циклом вы переписываете переменную `imgFON`, помещая в нее `Rect`:

```
imgFON = pygame.image.load('images/fon.png')
...
bges = []
bges.append(pygame.Rect(0, 0, 288, 512))
...

    for i in range(len(bges)-1, -1, -1):
        imgFON = bges[i]                  # !!!
        imgFON.x -= 1

    if imgFON.right < 0:
        bges.remove(imgFON)

...

    for fon in bges:
        window.blit(imgFON, fon)
```

---

**UPD.**

Обновил код в соответствии с рекомендациями выше:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 800, 600
FPS = 60

window = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

imgFON = pygame.image.load('images/fon.png')
imgBIRD = pygame.image.load('images/bird.png')
imgPB = pygame.image.load('images/PB.png')
imgPT = pygame.image.load('images/PT.png')
py, sy, ay = HEIGHT // 2, 0, 0
player = pygame.Rect(HEIGHT // 3, py, 50, 50)

state = 'start'
timer = 10

pipes = []
bges = []

bges.append(pygame.Rect(0, 0, 288, 512))

play = True
while play:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            play = False

    press = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    click = press[0] or keys[pygame.K_SPACE]

    if timer > 0:
        timer -= 1
    
    # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    for fon in reversed(bges):
        fon.x -= 1

    if fon.right < 0:
        bges.remove(fon)
    # !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

    for i in range(len(pipes)-1, -1, -1):
        pipe = pipes[i]
        pipe.x -= 3

        if pipe.right < 0:
            pipes.remove(pipe)


    if state == 'start':
        if click and timer == 0 and len(pipes) == 0:
            state = 'play'

        py += (HEIGHT // 2 - py) * 0.1
        player.y = py

    elif state == 'play':
        if click:
            ay = -2
        else:
            ay = 0

        py += sy
        sy = (sy + ay + 1) * 0.98
        player.y = py 

        if len(pipes) == 0 or pipes[len(pipes)-1].x < WIDTH - 200:
            pipes.append(pygame.Rect(WIDTH, 0, 52, 200))
            pipes.append(pygame.Rect(WIDTH, 400, 52, 200))

        if player.top < 0 or player.bottom > HEIGHT:
            state = 'fall'

        for pipe in pipes:
            if player.colliderect(pipe):
                state = 'fall'

    elif state == 'fall':
        sy, ay = 0, 0
        state = 'start'
        timer = 60


    window.fill(pygame.Color('black'))
    for fon in bges:
        window.blit(imgFON, fon)
    for pipe in pipes:
        if pipe.y == 0:
            rect = imgPB.get_rect(bottomleft = pipe.bottomleft)
            window.blit(imgPB, rect)
        else:
            rect = imgPT.get_rect(topleft = pipe.topleft)
            window.blit(imgPT, rect)

    window.blit(imgBIRD, player)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: получается мне надо вместо Rect поставить Surface?

Comment: Да, но я бы перефразировал, что скорее всего в `imgFON = bges[i]` не нужно использовать эту переменную для хранения значений из списка `bges` :) Кст, могу посоветовать как сделать проще код с `for i in range(len(bges)-1, -1, -1):`: `for fon in reversed(bges): fon.x -= 1`

Comment: Я сделал Surface вместо Rect, и заменил for i in range(len(bges)-1, -1, -1): на for fon in reversed(bges): fon.x -= 1 но теперь выходит новая ошибка ValueError: size needs to be (number width, number height). Или я сделал что то не то, я только изучаю это все, поэтому не до конца все понимаю.

Comment: @Bolev, вообще не представляю в каком месте у вас ошибка :) Добавьте к вопросу обновление: что поменяли и всю трассу ошибки

Comment: Я изменил код, посмотрите пожалуйста. А вот сама ошибка D:\Рабочий стол\Flappy Floppa>python bird.py
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.2)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Рабочий стол\Flappy Floppa\bird.py", line 23, in <module>
    bges.append(pygame.Surface(0, 0, 288, 512))
ValueError: size needs to be (number width, number height)

Comment: Проблема тут `bges.append(pygame.Surface(0, 0, 288, 512))`, у Surface нет таких параметров, поэтому и ошибка: https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html У Surface самого по себе нет координат x и y, есть размер. Думаю, вам нужно вернуть как было, но поменять цикл, чтобы не было в нем `imgFON = `, т.к. это переписывает переменную. И нужно было дополнить ваш вопрос новым кодом, а не менять на новый, т.к. поменялся контекст :) Я верну изменение ответа и добавлю новое

Comment: Спасибо вам. Очень благодарен. Все заработало. А можно с вами связаться во Вконтакте или телеграме? Если не трудно.

Comment: Я добавил еще один способ исправление, вся причина была в невнимательности.

Comment: @Bolev, пожалуйста :) Неа, если будут вопросы, то создавайте их тут, уверен найдутся те кто на них дадут ответ ;)